# Copy data from one excel sheet to another excel sheet

Tags: python, regex, excel, python-3.x, barcode-scanner

I was writing this script to search a number in a an excel sheet then copy the whole row associated to that number and then paste it to a new excel sheet. I wanted to copy the same data row after row and as much as I execute the program and save it. I tried to figure out the solution through many ways by searching similar problems in this community but it does not work. Below is the code.

```
   import xlsxwriter
   import xlrd
   import xlwt
   import math

   def open_file(path):
       wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
       sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

       for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
           row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)

           if row_value[2] == 68860:
              row = 0
              col = 0

              wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook('or.xlsx')
              ws = wbk.add_worksheet()

              ws.write('A1', row_value[0])
              ws.write('B1', row_value[1])
              ws.write('C1', row_value[2])
              row = row + 1

              wbk.close()
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       path = "ord.xlsx"
       open_file(path)
```

Any suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Edited Version: I solved the issue that I was facing. Now, I couldnt find a solution to prevent breaking of my serial port connection even when the .csv file is already open. Here is the explaination of the main background.

Actually the opiginal idea was to search the number by scanning a QR code containing that particular number and then write information to a new file if the number is found. I solved this problem by writing it to a .csv file instead of an Xlsx file. Now everything works fine except one problem which I am not able to crack it. I have connected my scanner via serial port. There would be many users who would open and access this .csv file any time. When the program is running and the file is closed the scanning part is working fine. But when the file is open and someone scans any qr code, certainly it will give an error that the .csv file is open and along with that the whole program breaks out and we have to run it again and again. Is there any possibility to how prevent the program breaking out and just continue even if the file is open ? Below is my code.

```
if(ser.isOpen()):
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while(1):

    y = ser.readline().decode("ASCII")

    if (str(y)!=''):
        if (str(y)!='\r'):
            if (str(y)!='\n'):
                print(y)
                for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):

                    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)

                    if int(y) == int(row_value[0]):

                        if re.match("(11\d+)", row_value[0]) is not None:

                            file = open('Function.csv', 'a')
                            file.write(str(row_value[0])+";"+str(row_value[1])+"\n")

                            file.close()
                            ser.close()
```

Comment: Do your own work. Or at least try.

Comment: You can not ask people to do the code for you. What you can do is ask help when you are stuck somewhere.
You can take help from there [link](https://github.com/ewino/qreader) .

Comment: Thank you for your comments and motivation. Certainly I have done my coding by myself and it is working to an extent the way I wanted. Now I need a small help. How can I ask that ? I will share my code

Comment: @Jay It's almost good enough to re-open. If you just specify *what* isn't working, or explain what you expect to get and what you actually get, then it'd be good

Comment: Hi ItamarG3, Thanks for your message, today we discussed that there will be a change in the program how it should work. So I will try to do the change and see results by myself first, if I stuck somewhere I will repost the code again. But thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

There is a but in your code. Each time you find that value (and they may be multiple rows with that vlaue, right?), you will write to new sheet.

If you open destination workbook before loop, and keep track of which row you should write next to you will get all those values into singe sheet.

Something like this snippet that use string interpolation:

```
def open_file(path):
   row_in_output = 1
   wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook('or.xlsx')
   ws = wbk.add_worksheet()
   [...]
          ws.write("A{row_in_output}", row_value[0])
          ws.write("B{row_in_output}", row_value[1])
          ws.write("C{row_in_output}", row_value[2])
          row = row + 1
          row_in_output = row_in_output + 1

          wbk.close()
```

PS I'm using Python 3.6 interpolation syntax. Adjust accordingly if you use older Python.

Comment: Hi, I get this error after launching- ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A{row_in_output}'. I tried to convert to string but it doesnt work and also i tried with float. But when I put the search number with in quotes the program executes but it does not write to target file

Comment: That would suggest string representing float is passed to int variable. Can you check what's row_in_output value just before that line? Also please add your python version into question.

Comment: Hi, I have just checked, you are right it is giving out float values for row_value.

Comment: I am using python 3.6

Comment: ['Resistor 1', 'Rs-Components', 10.0, 36.0, '', ''] ------ this is the printed output of row value, the number 36 is the number that was searched in the source excel file and rest are the data that is associated to it.

Comment: Ok. Look up type conversion float -> string in python.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message, Yes, I converted the floats to string here but to accomplish this in csv not is xls. Thanks for the help.